# Disable sound in thunderbird when sending an email via ctrl+enter?

Tags: thunderbird

I am using Mozilla Thunderbird 60.8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 and I use to send emails by using the Ctrl+Enter shortcut.

This opens a popup saying : "Are you sure you are ready to send this message?" like this one (in French):

[image: The actual popup]

This popup is great and it often saved me from sending an email too quickly, but it comes with the default critical sound which, when music is playing, is quite annoying!

Is there any way to keep the popup but disable the sound?

Comment: Did you check settings with in the thunderbird app? It is possible with in the OS but it may also stop other alerts..

Comment: I am afraid that indeed this may be solely connected to the default alerts of the system. To turn this one off, you need to turn of any of these sounds ("system sounds" in Settings - Sound)